# WPF How to bind data between user control and mainview?

Tags: c#, wpf, list, data-binding, user-controls

I'm trying to transfer list from mainview to user control. My solution doesn't work. Everything works fine except for the transferring the list.
My user control:

```
public List<Song> ListIWantTransferFromMainviewToUsercontrol = new List<Song>();
    public View_Playlist()
    {
        InitializeComponent();                  
        ToPlayList.ItemsSource = ListIWantTransferFromMainviewToUsercontrol;
        ToPlayList.Items.Refresh();
    }
```

My mainview:

```
        var i = Playlists_ListBox.Items.IndexOf(Playlists_ListBox.SelectedItem);
        string y = Playlists[i].Title;
        var z = Playlists[i].Songs;
        View_Playlist view_Playlist = new View_Playlist
        {
            ListIWantTransferFromMainviewToUsercontrol = z
        };
        this.contentControl.Content = view_Playlist;
```

I should click on item in listbox shown by mainview and run this code on click. Has anyone working solution for my problem? Thanks for reply.
User control XAML, listbox part:

```
<ListBox Name="ToPlayList" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="4" Background="{x:Null}" >
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="BlanchedAlmond" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseCaptured" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="0,2" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="205"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="90" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="90" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="35" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <CheckBox/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding SongTitle}"  Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding SongArtist}" Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding SongDate}" Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding Duration}" Foreground="White"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "doesn't work"?

Comment: PlayList is a different class.  You posted the constructor of the class.  Where is the data ToPlay being loaded?

Comment: @jdweng I forgot rename variable. It's correct now.

Comment: @bit ToPlayList - list box doesn't display data. When i seed ListIWantTransferFromMainviewToUsercontrol manually in usercontrol it is displayed so there must be problem with data binding.

Comment: Should be :  this.contentControl.Content = view_Playlist.ListIWantTransferFromMainviewToUsercontrol;

Comment: Can you share the XAML?

Comment: @bit of course. It's added to my question. Sorry for delay. If you want to se any other part of code, just write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by parameter. It isn't ideal, but working.